# Changing the Trac layout via custom CSS

Tags: css, layout, trac

**What I want to do:**
I want to change the standard Trac layout using a custom CSS file from my plugin. More specifically, I want to change the appearance of the navigation bar link of my plugin.

**What I have so far:**
I know that the navigation bar items automatically get a CSS class assigned to them. This looks like `class="iconPluginname"`. I created a new HTML file in my templates folder called `site.html`, which looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/"
      py:strip="">

  <!--! Add site-specific style sheet -->
  <head py:match="head" py:attrs="select('@*')">
    ${select('*')}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="${href.chrome('/mypluginname/css/mainnav_icon.css')}" />
  </head>

  <body py:match="body" py:attrs="select('@*')">
    ${select('*|text()')}
  </body>

</html>
```

As far as I know, Trac searches in the plugin files for a file called `site.html`, and if it doesn't find one it searches in the shared resources and finally in the Trac folder. The latter case is the default case. By my understanding, if I create a file `site.html` in my templates folder and the plugin is loaded correctly, it should automatically use the linked stylesheet and also add any changes done in the template. However, when I add a title tag to it, the title of my Trac page is not changed, so I assume the layout is not even loaded.

What do I have to do to make changes to the layout or add a custom stylesheet to my Trac, apart from adding `site.html` in my templates folder and linking to the stylesheet?

Comment: Why wouldn't a typical CSS override work in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If your Trac app plugin attaches a custom `iconPluginname` class to your nav structure, just do custom styles based off of it. `.iconPluginname .my-style{ whatever: youwant; }` or `.iconPluginname { .my-style{ whatever: youwant; } }` in scss.

Comment: That's what I am doing inside my CSS file. The problem is, that the HTML file, which should override the Trac layout and links to the CSS file, is not loaded, and I do not know why. I think I might be missing something for the template to be loaded, but I think that it should be loaded automatically if Trac finds it in the templates folder.

Comment: So the problem is HOW to apply the styles. I've read somewhere, that it is possible to create custom themes which can be done with just CSS styles without templates, but searching for Trac themes all I can find is plugins applying themes and [this](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/theme), but no documentation of how to make custom themes as described [here](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/theme).

Comment: Yeah just read that documentation you pointed out and it's terrible. Looks like you are doing things correctly above - try an absolute path to the CSS file. I've had issues where it was a path thing many times before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to provide custom site styling, put the `site.html` shown on the [TracInterfaceCustomization](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization#SiteAppearance) page in your environment `templates` directory and put the custom site styling in `style.css` in your environment `htdocs` directory.

If you'd like to add a stylesheet through a plugin you are developing, use [add_stylesheet](http://www.edgewall.org/docs/tags-trac-1.0/html/api/trac_web_chrome.html#trac.web.chrome.add_stylesheet).

Comment: This works. At first it didn't show the new style, but inspecting it in the browser I could see that the new properties were added, but inactive. So I had to add `!important` to the CSS in order to override the generic mainnav item properties.